# Can I make use of land that was purchased with an interest-based bank loan?

Tags: fiqh, riba

I have already bought a land. But to buy the land, I took some  loan (portion of total money needed to buy) from a  interest-based bank. Monthly basis I am still paying to the bank to return the money with interest. Now will you please educate me about the land, will it be halal for me to enjoy or use the land? Or what should I do with the land which I have already bought?

Comment: Where is the land located?